# yii relations to create relationships from multiple tables

Tags: yii, relationship

I have 3 tables.

> DEAL:-id,companyId, COMPANY:-id,userId,name,website,address
>   USER:-id,email,password,

I want email id of company. which is in  user table

currently i m working on deal

so in deal model what relations should i make?

thanks  in advance..

Answer (score 2):

Just add the company relation to your deal, you can chain the things together:

In Deal:

```
'company' => [self::BELONGS_TO, 'Company', 'companyId']
```

In Company:

```
'user' => [self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'userId']
```

Then you can do `$deal->company->user->email`

Answer (score 0):

As an extension of [Blizz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22680946/428543) you can use [`CActiveRelation::through`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRelation#through-detail) as follows to access a child relation without the parent relation i.e reduce the chaining

In Company:

```
'user' => [self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'userId']
```

In Deal:

```
'company' => [self::BELONGS_TO, 'Company', 'companyId'],
'user' => [self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'userId', 'through' => 'company']
```

Then you can do `$deal->user->email`